# same data when user push deep link

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

I got problem. I use deeplink to navigate some screen. The scheme is user go to the screen A without url, the data that app show in screen A is X and than user minimize the app. After that user push the link that navigate to screen A with passing data Y and its work the app show the screen A but the data is still X, it should data Y that the screen show. In this case I use react native to build the app. any one can halp me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: actually i don't know what code that should i input, because the problem is still in looking for in code